# R: Group in sparklyr ("sum", "count distinct" , "mean")

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

we have the following data hosted in the working directory:

```
 >library(sparklyr)
 >library(dplyr)

 >f<-data.frame(category=c("e","EE","W","S","Q","e","Q","S"), 
          DD=c(33.2,33.2,14.55,12,13.4,45,7,3),
          CC=c(2,44,4,44,9,2,2.2,4), 
 >FF=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","A") )

>write.csv(f,"D.csv")##Write in working directory
```

We  using spark commands to read the file from the Working directory

```
>sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = "/home/tomas/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/", version = "2.1.0")


>df <- spark_read_csv(sc, name = "data", path = "D.csv", header = TRUE, delimiter = ",")
```

I want to obtain a matrix like the following, in which is grouped by "category", sum DD, calculate the average of "CC", count different in "FF"

It would stay like this:

```
  category SumDD MeanCC CountDistinctFF
   e       78.2    2             1
   EE      33.2    44.           1
   WW      14.55   4             1
   S       15      24            2
   Q       20.4    5.6           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to manipulate spark DF you need to use dplyr functions. In the spark environment Naveen's answer will do except for the last variable. Instead of `unique` you can try `n_distinct` from dplyr

```
df0=df%>%group_by(category)%>%
summarize(sumDD=sum(DD,na.rm=T),MeanCC=mean(CC,na.rm=T),CountDistinctFF=n_distinct(FF))
```

To check your results as a spark DF you can use:

```
> glimpse(df0)
Observations: ??
Variables: 4
$ category        <chr> "e", "EE", "S", "Q", "W"
$ sumDD           <dbl> 78.20, 33.20, 15.00, 20.40, 14.55
$ MeanCC          <dbl> 2.0, 44.0, 24.0, 5.6, 4.0
$ CountDistinctFF <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 2, 1
```

or you can collect back to your local system and manipulate like any R data frame

```
    > df0%>%collect
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  category sumDD MeanCC CountDistinctFF
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>
1 e         78.2    2                 1
2 EE        33.2   44                 1
3 S         15     24                 1
4 Q         20.4    5.6               2
5 W         14.6    4                 1
```

Comment: Very, good, it works!

It has this exit. But it has no influence on the output:

Warning messages:
1: Missing values are always removed in SQL.
Use `SUM(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to silence this warning 
2: Missing values are always removed in SQL.
Use `AVG(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to silence this warning 


Is it due to something?

Comment: I updated the answer now you should not be getting the warnings

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if you are looking for a solution from a specific package, This can be achieved using `dplyr` package where we use `group_by` using `category` column and `summarise` the result based on our need.

Here is the sample code for it.

**Code:**

```
f %>% group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(sumDD = sum(DD), MeanCC = mean(CC), CountDistinctFF = length(unique(FF)))
```

**Output:**

```
  category sumDD MeanCC CountDistinctFF
  <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>           <int>
1 e         78.2    2                 1
2 EE        33.2   44                 1
3 Q         20.4    5.6               2
4 S         15     24                 1
5 W         14.6    4                 1
```

Comment: Hello, the output shows me an error:                                                                    
                                                                                                                              
     Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'UNIQUE'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 71

Answer (score 1):

In a complementary way to the response of Antonis, later an error appeared. Investigating I found that there was a conflict between packages, specifically: dplyr and SparkR.

This is solved by installing the tidyverse package and calling the commands as follows:

```
 >library(tidyverse)

  >df0=df%>%dplyr::group_by(category)%>%dplyr::summarize(sumDD=sum(DD,na.rm=T),MeanCC=mean(CC,na.rm=T),CountDistinctFF=n_distinct(FF))



>glimpse(df0)
 Observations: ??
 Variables: 4
 $ category        <chr> "e", "EE", "S", "Q", "W"
 $ sumDD           <dbl> 78.20, 33.20, 15.00, 20.40, 14.55
 $ MeanCC          <dbl> 2.0, 44.0, 24.0, 5.6, 4.0
 $ CountDistinctFF <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 2, 1
```